# NumPy import error in C2V - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath:

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a problem with an .exe compiled with pyinstaller .

I use the c2v library to manage images and it contains numpy which is apparently the cause of the error

the log error =

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numpy\core\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "numpy\core\overrides.py", line 6, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SRBR.py", line 23, in <module>
    from albumart import albumartfun
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "albumart.py", line 9, in <module>
    from removesimbols import removestring
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "cv2\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "numpy\core\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.10 from "D:\SRBRdev\SRBR.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.23.2"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.
```

I've already reinstalled the entire python including the libraries, python is running in GLOBAL mode, in VSC the code works normally.

I've already tried previous versions of numpy and importing numpy in the main code.

I also tried to add numpy path in pyinstaller

if you find a solution, thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried setting up a virtual environment with all of the necessay libraries? Is it possible that you are using that environment in VSC, but haven't activated the env in the terminal you are trying to build the executable from?

Comment: `numpy` uses code in C/C++ and it mya use external `C/C++` libraries for calculations - and it may need to install some C/C++ library manually (because it is not Python module). You could check in documentation if numpy has some requirements.. BTW: error shows link https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html and there you can see some of C/C++ libraries: `libf77blas` and `libatlas`

Comment: @furas thanks for replying, I installed the C/C++ development package because it was required by a previous version of numpy in your installation

Comment: @nstvnsn Thanks for replying, I haven't done that procedure yet, I'll try

Comment: @nstvnsn
I created a virtual environment for the project and installed all the libs in it and the error persists

Comment: do you have this problem when you run code without converting to `.exe`? File exe may need to add some C/C++ libraries manually because `pyinstaller` may not find it.

Comment: @furas they mentioned the code runs from VCS, so it runs before compiling to a .exe file. I think you may be on to it.

Comment: @furas I will try to add the libraries you mentioned above

Comment: error message doesn't show details. It doesn't show which `.DLL` makes problem. It shows only problem in `numpy\core\__init__.py", line 49, ... Import Error` - so maybe you could check this line in source code to see what it tries to import. Path to folder with `numpy` you should get with `import numpy` and `print( numpy.__file__ )`

Comment: @furas It looks comical but this line of code is for a raise error with the error message.
https://pastecode.io/s/ppv4g61s

Comment: I checked this code and it hard to say what is the problem - but in folder `numpy/core` I see files like `_multiarray_umath` (on my Linux with extension `.so` and this means C/C++ library - on Windows it may have extension `.DLL` ) and probably these files are missing in `.exe`. You could run `pyinstalled` with option `--onedir` instead of `--onefile` - to create folder with all files which it adds to `.exe` and you can see if there are these files `.DLL`. And it may need to [use Spec file](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html) to add missing file manually.

Comment: @furas I ran in --onedir and this time the error is different = https://pastecode.io/s/okvs60zt

The only file related to _multiarray_umath is located in a folder SRBR\numpy\core
and is named by = _multiarray_umath.cp310-win_amd64.pyd